# How to layout canvas and table/list horiontally in html?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, layout

> I want to layout both canvas and table/list horizontal in one page
>
> left side, I have a canvas and it has fixed width and height with many polygons
>   right side, I will have list with many lines of text, when I click one line of text, it will show various of lines at left side canvas
>
> here is sample code, whatever I tried, it always layout vertically instead of horizontally,  any clue?

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

</style>

<script src="index.js"> </script>
<body>
   <div class="flex-container">
            </div class="flex-left">
                <div class = "leftside">
                    <canvas class="canvasView" id="myCanvas" width = "200" height = "300">
                        Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
                    </canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="flex-right">
                    <div class = "rightside">
                        <table id="my_table" class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Detour_Percentage</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that your html is invalid for bootstrap function due to multiple singular **div** tags. Kindly correct them. This is the first thing that should be corrected.

[image]

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-left">
        <div class = "leftside">
            <canvas class="canvasView" id="myCanvas" width = "200" height = "300">
                    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-right">
        <div class = "rightside">
            <table id="my_table" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Detour_Percentage</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please try this html. With bootstrap, singular div tags do not work.

Comment: HI Sandeep, thanks, Seems I made a stupid mistake, after correct it, it works now